# Lille Metro schedule... is it 24/7?

Tags: trains, france, lille

The M1 and M2 lines in Lille, France have a confusing [schedule](https://moovitapp.com/index/en/public_transit-line-M1-Lille-3750-858400-656173-0). It's 7 days per week, but it looks like it's "running" basically 24h hours per day (minus some ten-minute delay). I never took the metro later than 11 PM when I was in Lille last year, but people told me that it stops just before midnight. But... it looks like it starts right back up again immediately, after about 10 minutes.

**What are the *actual* hours of the Lille M1 and M2 lines?** I have a hard time believing that they're 24/7...

Comment: https://www.transpole.fr/fr/ provides time tables that doesn't seem to mention trains on M1 and M2 lines between midnight and 5 AM (approx).

Comment: Note that there are indeed 24/7 metro systems out there: http://mic-ro.com/metro/24h.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an error in how Movit is calculation for the first and last train. It seems to be assuming the first train of the day is the first train after midnight, and the last train the last train before midnight. The system does shut down overnight, but as the last train is after midnight this error has occurred.

Click "VIEW FULL SCHEDULE" and then the name of an individual stop to see the first and last train for each stop; here they are shown correctly.

Comment: Yep, as soon as I clicked a stop like you mentioned in your comment, I could scroll to see the first train is at 5-ish AM, and the last is just after midnight.

So yeah, definitely a software bug/slight usability issue. Go figure :)

Comment: There’s a good reason why Google Maps doesn’t try to tell you the ‘first’ and ‘last’ services. It’s essentially impossible to automate (does a 24hr service have a first and last? What time should be taken as the cutoff - clearly 12am doesn’t work, etc) - as we see here.

Comment: Google maps does offer a last service option though Tim, although otherwise I fully agree with you

Answer (score 7):

There is a night train, but it's only during weekends and aimed at 'student locations' https://www.transpole.fr/cms/institutionnel/se-deplacer/ligne-de-nuit/. It also runs during big 'party' events like the annual braderie, or probably new year.  Regular schedule stops at midnight and resumes at 5am.

Comment: Wow, that is really good to know!